# Wordpress - edit media.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert category description after native media player.

For category description, I use this code:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
    $url = get_term_link((int)$category->term_id,'category');
    $categories[$key] =
    "<dd>{$category->category_description}</dd>";
}
 echo "<dl>\n" . implode("\n",$categories) . "\n</dl>";
```

but after I edit media.php (The Video shortcode), category description is displayed abode media player.

Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: Never edit files in /wp-includes and /wp-admin. Never.

Comment: Do you know another way to add category description after video player?

Comment: I wouldn't mess up with video shortcode, as it's job is to view the video itself. It seems like template-related job, not content-related.